# Making a void* within a struct point to an integer

Tags: c, void-pointers, ansi-c

I have a struct as follows:

```
typedef struct Node {
    void* data;
    unsigned long id;
    NodePtr next;
    NodePtr prev;
} Node;
```

It is meant to be a node in a linked list ADT. I have 2 different constructors depending on what the Node needs to hold in data. One constructor uses:

```
NodePtr TempNode;
TempNode = malloc( sizeof(Node) );
/* Other stuff */
TempNode->data = newList();
return (TempNode);
```

And this seems to work just fine for letting me access that list by returning (List->current->data) where current is a Node pointer in the List Struct

However, I want to make a version of the constructor where (data) points to an int. I've read that I can do this by doing the following

```
void* ptr;
int x = 0;
*((int*)ptr) = x;
```

But with the way my constructor is set up, that would mean I have to do something like this?

```
*((int*)TempNode->data) = 1; // data starts at 1
```

And this doesn't work. I'm very new to C so I don't understand much of the terminology. I read that dereferencing (using the -> notation?) cannot be done with void*'s, but it seems to work fine in my list version of the constructor. How can I rewrite my other constructor to cast this void* to an int?

Comment: The pointer *needs* to point at some specific storage that you are allowed to use. It can be automatic, static, threat-local, or dynamic, but you *may not* just use whatever bit of memory it happens to point at!

Comment: But doesn't that mean my calls to List->current->data shouldn't return a List for the case where data was set to = newList()? It seems like they do.

Comment: No, because in that case you *set* `data`. In the other case you are just accepting whatever value happened to be in the memory that was handed you for your `Node` (which could be literally *any* value expressible in `sizeof(void*)` bytes).

Answer (score 2):

I strongly counsel against doing this, but if you really want to use the `void *` member to hold an integer, you can do:

```
Node *constructor_int(int n)
{
    Node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
    /* Other stuff */
    tmp->data = (void *)n;
    return(tmp);
}
```

This involves the minimum number of casts and avoids most problems with relative sizes of types.

The obvious, logical way to do it is to allocate an integer for the `data` member to point at:

```
Node *constructor_int(int n)
{
    Node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
    /* Other stuff */
    tmp->data = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(int *)temp->data = n;
    return(tmp);
}
```

You just have to remember to free the two memory allocations.

The code should also check that the memory allocations succeeded before using the results.

Comment: +1 I expected to see `intptr_t` come into this answer somewhere, but the more I thought about it the best "do it right" answer is the closing double alloc. One may be tempted to marry the two into a single alloc (sizeof(int) + sizeof(*tmp)) and set the relative offsets, but there are platforms where that will cause alignment errors (not many, but some). Nice answer.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean I can treat NodePtr->data as an int now? and in other areas of code call List->current->data++?

Comment: You have to treat it as a `void *` that can legitimately be cast to `int *` and dereferenced.  Hence `(*(int *)ModePtr->data)++` and `(*(int *)List->current->data)++` would be be OK.  I'd probably work to avoid needing to do this very often — I'd look at the design of the whole system and see whether there's a better way to do things — possibly even moving away from a single ADT to use one ADT for the integer list and another ADT for the one used with `newList()` (where the abstractness gets called into question).  If you really want template types, maybe you should consider C++.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand now. I agree with you about the ADT split, that's probably what I would do if I had more time.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about this

When you do something like

```
NodePtr TempNode;
TempNode = malloc( sizeof(Node) );
```

you have asked the library to reseve you some dynamic storage which is big enough for a `Node`. The initial values of that memory are undefined, so right now the pointer `TempNode->data` could point *anywhere* and probably does not point at memory reserved for your use.

When you do

```
TempNode->data = newList();
```

you give the pointer a (presumably, as long as `newList()` does something legal and sensible) valid value;

If instead you do

```
*((int*)TempNode->data) = 1;
```

you instruct the compiler to

1. treat `TempNode->Data` as a pointer-to-int,
2. de-reference it and
3. set the value of what every memory is at the other end to `1` (notice that at no point have you set `data` itself, just whatever it points at)

***But you don't know what it points to!*** De-referencing it is undefined behavior and strictly a bad thing.

You are always responsible for ensuring that you do not de-reference a pointer unless it points to memory that you are entitled to use.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what you're saying, but I'm still not sure what the best course of action is. How can I make data point to an area I can use?

Comment: Local variable, global variable, dynamic allocations (the return values from the `alloc` family of function) are all bits you can use (at least until the local variables go out of scope or you `free()` dynamic allocations).

Answer (score 1):

"*How can I make data point to an area I can use*?"

I'm not sure if you mean what I'm going to explain below (and it won't be short :P), but if you are asking how you can distinguish the type of the data stored in `Node->data`, then with that implementation you cannot.

You leave it up to the end-programmer to remember what type of data he has stored into the list (which is not a bad thing btw.. on the contrary, it is the norm). In other words, you trust the end-programmer that he/she will apply the proper casts when say printing the `Node->data`.

If for some reason you wish to provide a more managed API for your list, you could add one more field in a `List` struct, for identifying the type of the data stored in your list.

For example...

```
enum DataType {
    DT_INVALID = 0,
    DT_PTR
    DT_CHAR,
    DT_INT,
    DT_FLOAT,
    DT_DOUBLE,
    ...
    /* not a data-type, just their total count */
    DT_MAX
};
#define DT_IS_VALID(dt)    ( (dt) > DT_INVALID && (dt) < DT_MAX )

typedef struct List List;
struct List {
    enum DataType dt;
    Node  *head;
};
```

Of course you are free to support less or more data-types than the ones I listed in the `enum`, above (even custom ones, say for strings, or whatever you see fit according to your project).

So first you'll need a constructor (or initializer) for a list, something like this...

```
List *new_list( enum DataType dt )
{
    List *ret = NULL;

    if ( !DT_IS_VALID(dt) )
        return NULL;

    ret = malloc( sizeof(List) );
    if ( NULL == ret )
        return NULL;

    ret->dt = dt; 
    ret->head = NULL;

    return ret;
}
```

and instantiate it, say like this...

```
int main( void )
{
    List *listInt = new_list( DT_INT );
    if ( NULL == list ) {
        /* handle failure here */
    }
```

Now that you have already stored the intended data-type into the list meta-data, you are free to choose how you will implement the `Node` constructors. For example, a generic one could look something like this...

```
int list_add_node( List *list, const void *data )
{
    Node *node = NULL;
    size_t datasz = 0;

    /* sanity checks */
    if ( !list || !data || !DT_IS_VALID(list->dt) )
        return 0;  /* false */

    node = malloc( sizeof(Node) );
    if ( NULL == node )
        return 0; /* false */

    /* when data points to mem already reserved say for an array (TRICKY) */
    if ( DT_PTR == list->dt ) {  
        node->data = data;
    }
    /* when data points to mem reserved for a primitive data-type */
    else {
        datasz = dt_size( list->dt );  /* implement dt_size() according to your supported data-types */
        node->data = malloc( datasz );
        if ( NULL == node->data ) {
            free( node );
            return 0; /* false */
        }
        memcpy(node->data, data, datasz );
    }

    /* add here the code dealing with adding node into list->head */
    ...
    return 1; /* true */
}
```

For `DT_PTR` (which I flagged as **TRICKY** in the example) it is more safe to implement a different `Node` constructor, perhaps accepting 2 extra arguments, lets say `elemsz` and `nelems`, so the function can allocate `elemsz * nelems` bytes for copying the `data` contents into them, in case `data` points to an array, a struct or any other non-primitive type. Or you can provide an extra `DT_ARR` enum value specifically for arrays. You are free to do whatever suits you best.

In any case, for `DT_PTR` the example above relies on the caller of `list_add_node` to have properly allocated the passed `data`, and in general context this is **not** a good thing at all.

The code is more complicated, but you know the data-type stored in your list. So for at least the primitive data-types you can add say a printing routine that automatically casts its output according to `list->dt` (for non-primitive data types you should provide support for custom printing routines, usually via callback functions).

You can even take it to the extreme, and move the `dt` field from `List` to `Node`. In that case you implement a list of heterogeneous data in the nodes, but it gets much more complicated and also its rarely useful (if ever).

All this ADT stuff via (void *) pointers have serious performance issues, that's why speed critical implementations utilize (or abuse if you prefer) the pre-processor instead, for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the indepth explanation. I know that my way of doing it isn't optimal, and leaves room for error. Luckily it seems that Jonathan Leffler's explanation seems to work for my purposes. When I get a chance I'll sit down and really take a look at your post so I can really understand whats going on. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome (btw I just fixed some typos, there may be more though). Since Jonathan's answer was the most helpful, consider accepting it when your rep goes a bit higher ;)